# Why acts_as_taggable_on doesn't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm trying to implement acts_as_taggable_on. I follow the tutorial, but this doesn't work and I don't know why..

Artigo.rb

```
class Artigo < ActiveRecord::Base

 acts_as_taggable_on :tags

end
```

Artigos_controller.rb

```
 def show
  @artigo = Artigo.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @artigo.tag_list.add("awesome")
end
```

the gem generated the tables `tags` and `taggings`

This is the console:

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images with code. Some people have a small screen (11' or 9').

Comment: sorry...I can't copy it from console

Comment: you don't say. just select then right click and copy... or select and `Ctrl+Shift+C`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `save` to save the tags

```
@artigo.tag_list.add("awesome")
@artigo.save
```